# Make a picture rounded and align text

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying o customize a CSS in order to have a better menu...

Let me explain better:

if you go to http://italiancrypto.it/account/ and sign in with

User: Test00
PW: !F$!l%t26PE8c(u72zI*onUI

you will see that in the menu bar there will be the name ()FIRST LAST) and a small picture...

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoX0A.png)

I have two problems with the CSS?

1) the picture should be "rounded" and not just plain square.

2) the menu is not aligned....

How can I fix this in CSS? if I make the picture round and smaller I think I can fix the alignment as well...

HTML:

```
<li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-663"><a href="#">John Smith <img onerror="this.src='http://italiancrypto.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg';" src="http://graph.facebook.com/10213039741163029/picture?width=200&amp;height=200" class="func-um_user gravatar avatar avatar-40 um-avatar um-avatar-default" width="40" height="40" alt="John Smith" pagespeed_url_hash="390260811" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-662" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-580 current_page_item menu-item-662"><a href="http://italiancrypto.it/account/">Account</a>    </li><li id="menu-item-654" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-654"><a href="http://italiancrypto.it/logout/">Logout</a></li></ul>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
Inherited from ul#menu-main-menu.vlog-main-nav.vlog-menu
min.css?ver=1.8.1:1
how to fix the CSS?
```

Inside the LI item, I have a text and a picture... I should make the picture "rounded and smaller"... I am not too sure how to do that wvia CSS...

many thanks

Reagards

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.